# Multiple button initialization

Tags: android, button, findviewbyid

I have ~10 buttons and I want to initialize them by calling a method. I mean now I have a lot of:

```
button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

I want to have a method like this and call it for every button initialization:

```
private void initialize(Button mybutton){
  mybutton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
}
```

Comment: Have you try your method? What do you see?

Comment: yes you can do that. You will have to pass button name and id too.

Comment: Sure, but it gives an error on mybutton ( R.id.mybutton ). Says ca n not resolve symbol mybutton.

Comment: Use [Butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) . Its an awesome work by JW, used to bind view to their functionality, No need for lots of boilerplate code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way pass Your `Button` as well as `ID` of Your `Button`

change `initialize` like this

```
private void initialize(Button mybutton, int ID){
  mybutton= (Button) findViewById(ID);
}
```

and call Your `initialize` method like this

```
initialize(button,R.id.button)
```

Comment: @abrutsze you can accept this answer now so it can help others also

Answer (score 3):

```
private Button initialize(int ID){
  return (Button) findViewById(ID);
}
```

and use it like this

`button1= initialize(R.id.button1);`

Answer (score 1):

**Do Like this**

```
ArrayList<Button> buttons=new ArrayList<>();

String[] buttonIds = {R.id.btn1,R.id.btn2,R.id.btn3};

for(int i=0;i<buttonIds.length-1;i++)
{
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(buttonIds[i]);
    buttons.add(b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass all your buttons with their respective id's in this method:

```
private void initialize(){
  button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
  button1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
  ...
}
```

And call the `initialize()` in your `onCreate()` method

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to use **ButterKnife**. You can have a good notes on ButterKnife [here](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)

```
  @BindView(R.id.title) TextView title;
  @BindView(R.id.subtitle) TextView subtitle;
  @BindView(R.id.footer) TextView footer;
```

This is an example of `initialisation` and `declaration` using `ButterKnife`